# Not able to access environment variable in SCSS file

Tags: sass, environment-variables, next.js

```js
module.exports = withPlugins([
    [withImages],
    [withStyles, {
        less: true,
        sass: true,
        modules: false,
        lessLoaderOptions: {
            javascriptEnabled: true,
            modifyVars: themeVariables,
        },
        sassLoaderOptions: {
            prependData: `$brand: '${process.env.THEME}';`,
        },
    }],
], nextConfig);
```

How to access environment variable in scss Next.js tried adding above configuration inside `next.config.js` file not able to access those variables in scss.

Comment: Just to double-check, is the environment variable set? Can you see `process.env.THEME`'s value if you console log it in `next.config.js`?

Comment: Yes. I can see the value

Comment: did you solve this? And if so, how?